# commands from root and commands from sudo

Tags: 14.04, command-line, permissions

`sudo cp -f ~/Download/foo.txt ~/Download/bar/` or other commandand its executed  (It isn't "cp" command centered question), so which is the difference between execute one command from sudo or from root?
Because the recommendation about to try to not work from root if it's not neceserary, So, It's that a recommendation in the context of running more complex instructions?

Comment: In Ubuntu, the root user does not have a password and can't be logged into.  This is a crucial difference with Ubuntu vs. Debian and such.  Further, `~` is resolve to your home directory directly because it's analyzed before `sudo` so the path isn't the `root` user's home directory, it's yours.  There's a ton of other reasons `sudo` and `root`-executed commands aren't *that* different but the core reason is in Ubuntu, there is no 'root' user password (it's disabled by default) and you need to `sudo` to run things as superuser.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  You only gave one command.  You don't need sudo to copy files from a path under your home directory to another path under your home directory.  You shouldn't use sudo unless you need to use sudo. Using sudo is essentially the same as running the command as the root user.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/   *Are you really using 14.04?  If not, why did you tag it? Note some command can have slight differences on releases*

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo` command by itself does not imply permissions to do something, but instead changes your user ID for the duration of the command.  By not specifying a username or ID, you are defaulting to become 'root' for a short period.  Thus, doing `sudo....` or loging in as root and doing the command, are the same thing.

from `man sudo`

> ```
> DESCRIPTION
>       sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or an‐
>       other user, as specified by the security policy.  The invoking user's
>       real (not effective) user-ID is used to determine the user name with
>       which to query the security policy.
> ```
>
> .....
>
> ```
>  -u user, --user=user
>              Run the command as a user other than the default target user
>              (usually root).  The user may be either a user name or a nu‐
>              meric user-ID (UID) prefixed with the ‘#’ character (e.g., #0
>              for UID 0).  When running commands as a UID, many shells re‐
>              quire that the ‘#’ be escaped with a backslash (‘\’).  Some
>              security policies may restrict UIDs to those listed in the
>              password database.  The sudoers policy allows UIDs that are
>              not in the password database as long as the targetpw option
>              is not set.  Other security policies may not support this.
> ```